# Build Chromium version number 60

Tags: git, chromium, gclient

i need to build an old version of Chromium for Android, version number 60.
I'm following below steps:

1. git clone
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
2. export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/depot_tools"
3. mkdir ~/chromium && cd
   ~/chromium
4. fetch --nohooks --no-history android
5. git fetch
       https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git
       +refs/tags/60.0.3112.116:chromium_60.0.3112.116 --depth 1
6. gclient sync --with_branch_heads --with_tags

The recipe is reported [here](https://chromium.org/developers/how-tos/get-the-code/working-with-release-branches).

Last step fail with below error:

> Syncing projects:  80% (21/26) src/third_party/cld_2/src
>
> src/media/cdm/api (ERROR)
>   ---------------------------------------- [0:00:00] Started.
>   ---------------------------------------- Error: Command 'git checkout --quiet 46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112' returned non-zero exit status 128 in /root/chromium/src/media/cdm/api fatal:
>   reference is not a tree: 46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112

Where 46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112 is related to [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/cdm/+/46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112) commit on chromium / chromium / cdm.

Do you have some experiences/ideas about it?

Thank you,
best regards

Comment: What is output of `gclient sync --with_branch_heads` call ?

Comment: Can you try this: `gclient sync` then followed by `gclient sync --with_branch_heads`?

Comment: For both output is

Syncing projects:  81% (22/27) src/third_party/catapult

src/media/cdm/api (ERROR)
----------------------------------------
[0:00:00] Started.
----------------------------------------
Error: Command 'git checkout --quiet 46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112' r                                                                                                                                                      eturned non-zero exit status 128 in /chromium/src/media/cdm/api
fatal: reference is not a tree: 46eebfa522b06c1f0b52b4233caa56793badf112

Comment: @Premier so I've tried locally. Even though I have 74 version I was able to checkout version you mentioned. Using simply `gclient sync --with_branch_heads`. Had to reset few repos but eventually sync was successful. 
So could you try one more time but use `fetch android`. Yes it would be longer. Then simply do `git fetch --tags` and `git checkout  60.0.3112.116`. From this stem run `gclient sync --with_branch_heads`.